# Emacs: some programs only work in ansi-term, some programs only work in shell

Tags: shell, emacs, terminal, ansi-term

Relative Emacs newbie here, just trying to adapt my programming workflow to fit with emacs. So far I've discovered shell-pop and I'm quite enjoying on-demand terminals that pop up when needed for banging out the odd commands.

What I understand so far about Emacs is that `shell` is a "dumb" terminal that doesn't support any ansi control codes, and that makes it incompatible with things like ncurses that attempt to draw complex UI's on a terminal emulator. This is why you can't use `less` or `top` or similar in shell-mode.

However, I seem to be having trouble with `ansi-term`, it's not the be-all, end-all that it's cracked up to be. Sure, it has no problems running `less` or `git log` or even `nano`, but there are a few things that can't quite seem to display properly when they're running in an `ansi-term`, such as `apt-get` and `nosetests`. I'm not sure quite what the name is for it, but `apt-get`'s output is characterised by live-updating what is displayed on the very last line, and then having unchanging lines of text scroll out above that line. It seems to be halfway between something like `less` and something dumber, like `cat`. Somehow `ansi-term` doesn't like this at all, and I get very garbled output, where it seems to output everything on one line only or just generally lose it's place and output things all over, randomly. In the case of `nosetests`, it starts off ok, but if any libraries spew out any STDERR, the output all goes to hell in a similar way.

With some fiddling it seems possible to fix this by mashing `C-l` and `RET`, but it's not always reliable.

Does anybody know what's going on here? Is there some way to fix `ansi-term` so that it can display everything properly? Or is there perhaps some other mode that I don't know about that is way better? Ideally I'd like something that "just works" as effortlessly as, eg, Gnome Terminal, which can run all of the above mentioned programs without a single hiccup.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like `term` behaves slightly better than `ansi-term` but it's not clear to me what the differences are between these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by commenting out my entire .emacs.el and then uncommenting and restarting emacs for every single line in the file. I discovered that the following line alone was responsible for the issue:

```
   '(fringe-mode 0 nil (fringe))
```

(this line disables the fringes from inside custom-set-variables).

I guess this is a bug in Emacs, that disabling the fringe causes term-mode to garble it's output really badly whenever any output line exceeds $COLUMN columns.

Anyway, I don't really like the fringes much at all, and it seems I was able to at least disable the left fringe without triggering this issue:

```
(set-fringe-mode (cons 0 8))
```

Comment: I don't know if fringe-mode is a global mode or a buffer-local one, but if it is buffer-local you can probably enable it only in term buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe apt-get does different things based on the `$TERM` environment variable. What happens if you set `TERM=dumb`? If that makes things work, then you can experiment with different values until you find one that supports enough features but still works.

Comment: I've been fiddling with this some more, changing various emacs settings, and what it actually seems like is that inside a `term`, any command that outputs lines longer than the width of the terminal will cause this problem. That's why `apt-get` would only do it intermittently, because it's line lengths are inconsistent between sessions, depending on how fast the internet can download what it's downloading. I found a text file where `cat foo.txt` causes this issue 100% reliably, but only if the terminal buffer is narrower than it's longest line. make it wider and it's fine. Any ideas?

Comment: More fiddling, it seems like the specific combination of setting `truncate-lines` to nil, `truncate-partial-width-windows` to nil, and `word-wrap` to t seems to stop the garbling issue, giving me a workable shell, however it causes goofy-looking wrapping where the shell and emacs can't seem to agree how to wrap. Eg, a very long line will show emacs wrapping on the word boundary, but then the terminal wraps again partway through the word, and then the line continues onto a third line below... very odd.

Comment: Yeah, near as I can figure, any terminal output beyond the width of the window will cause this garbling, and `word-wrap` mode just prevents it from happening by forcing wrapping before the lines get too long, even if it is a bit of an ugly solution. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: After an *exhaustive* line by line audit of my .emacs.el, I've discovered that this issue is triggered by disabling the fringe. All that `word-wrap` stuff was just a red herring. Commenting out the line `'(fringe-mode 0 nil (fringe))` (from inside `custom-set-variables`) has resolved the issue, and allows `cat` to work in my terminal correctly. Now I wonder if it's possible to disable the fringe everywhere but the terminal...

Comment: Hah, ok. I've given you some upvotes for being the only responder. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Note that git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014) now better detects dumb terminal when displaying verbose messages.
That *might* help Emacs better display some of the messages received from git, but the `fringe-mode` bug reported above is certainly the main cause.

See [commit 38de156](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38de156a05a4421103e93d43b36e9967e63fb707) by [Michael Naumov (`mnaoumov`)](https://github.com/mnaoumov)

#### `sideband.c`: do not use ANSI control sequence on non-terminal

> Diagnostic messages received on the sideband #2 from the server side are sent to the standard error with ANSI terminal control sequence "`\033[K`" that erases to the end of line appended at the end of each line.
>
> However, some programs (e.g. GitExtensions for Windows) read and interpret and/or show the message without understanding the terminal control sequences, resulting them to be shown to their end users.
> To help these programs, squelch the control sequence when the standard error stream is not being sent to a tty.